# Inject nifi web-api bean into custom processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I am playing around with NiFi custom processor.
How can I inject an instance of `org.apache.nifi.web.StandardNiFiServiceFacade` into my custom processor instance?

**Background:**

I am trying to achieve the goal of stopping the processor after the processor is executed. I understand that nifi processors are meant only for stream processing and not for batch processing, in which we execute the job just once. But to leverage on the NiFi execution support, this need to be done. As experimented further, I will be able to do that with the instance of `StandardNiFiServiceFacade` available in the custom processor instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not made available to the processor API intentionally.  If you are certain you want have the processor tell the controller to stop scheduling it then it can make an HTTP/REST API call to the API as would be the case for the user interface or programmatic API calls.

Processors should, however, never be doing this.  They are either scheduled to execute or not scheduled to execute.  If the conditions to perform some function are no longer as needed then the processor can check for these conditions and short-circuit its on trigger call and simply return.  If the conditions to perform some function are present then it can run them.

Comment: That helped!! I am doing it by calling "PUT /processors/{id}" and stopping the processor.

Answer (score 2):

If you are triggering this custom processor from an upstream processor such as GenerateFlowFile, you may be able to leverage ExecuteScript to emulate a "one-and-done" job trigger, check out [my blog post](https://funnifi.blogspot.com/2018/08/one-and-done-flows-aka-job-processing.html) for Groovy script(s) that might help you achieve what you're trying to do.